# Is there a way to downloads VSIXes from the VS Code Marketplace without a rate limit?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, rate-limiting, invoke-webrequest

I want to mass download vscode and a few addons from marketplace as `*.vsix`.
Is there a way to authentice myself or in anyway circumvent the rate limit?

Something between 20 and 50% of all downloads get finished.

```
# Hashtable of direct download links with lots of links
$Addons = [ordered]@{
    PowerShell             = "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode/vsextensions/PowerShell/latest/vspackage";
    CPlusPlus              = "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode/vsextensions/cpptools/latest/vspackage";
}
```

```
# Download from $Addons hashtable
foreach ($Key in $Addons.Keys) {
    $Url = $($Addons[$Key])
    Invoke-WebRequest $Url -OutFile "$Key.vsix"
}
```

I receive the following error since Marketplace has quite strict rate limits.

```bash
Invoke-WebRequest $Url -OutFile "$Key.vsix"
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of
resource 'Count' in namespace 'AnonymousId'. For more information on why your request was
blocked, see the topic \"Rate limits\" on the Microsoft Web site
(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950).","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.
Framework.Server.RequestBlockedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
"typeKey":"RequestBlockedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Comment: Following [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops#api-client-experience) in the error message, it says there should be a `Retry-After` header in the response that tells you how long in seconds to wait.  Maybe you can read that value and wait before retrying your request in your script.